Is there any common knowlege about inclusitivity-vs-exclusivity of ‘till/until’ time points?
Is it “common knowledge” agreed upon by all native speakers worldwide that the word till can variously be used both inclusive and also exclusive of its end point, depending on the context?
So for example, in I am on leave till Friday, sometimes this means that I might still be out Friday but sometimes it means that I might already be back to work Friday.
Do native speakers realize that you cannot tell which is meant here?

This question is similar to: The ambiguous "until". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is the same issue that arises when saying by Friday. Nobody realizes that some speakers use by to mean before here while other speakers do not do so.

@tchrist I don't see how "by Friday" excludes Friday itself, unless the context is such that "Friday" is to be understood as "Friday 8am".

@ryang Yeah well, this happened at work. You got in trouble for not having it down BEFORE Friday even though they said it had to be done "by Friday". The moment it became Friday if it had not been done you were penalized.

@ryang In business correspondence it's common to be specific like "by EOB Friday", to avoid any confusion.

The same confusion arises with the word "next". If today is Sunday, "next" Friday is five days away. But if today is Thursday "next" Friday may be eight days away. (Resolved by using "this week" or "next week")

This follows the same ambiguity as the usage of "until" in this context, and has been asked before.
I would assume that the sentence above is exclusive and means that the person would be in on Friday, though this seems to be exclusive to absence-related timeframes.

Ok, but the point I want to know is whether this concept is common knowledge among the general populace. because I am from India and I have never been taught this stuff in school, nor I have ever heard people discuss about the usage of till as inclusive or exclusive of the end point. Want to know your opinion on this.

In your specific scenario, it almost always suggests that the person will be in on Friday. It is difficult to summarise the thoughts of all speakers of a language, but I assume most would agree.

I understand, but is the general populace aware that the word 'till' can be used as both inclusive or exclusive of the end point depending on the context
